# Figuring out the Folder Index in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

I know that I can access Inbox using "FolderInbox".
When I debug my code, it reveals that FolderInbox has Index 6.

How can I get to other folders ? How can I find out its index?
The folder I need to acess is a Functional Mailbox.

Thanks.

Part of my code:

```
Dim MyArray(10) As String
Dim Msg As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim J As Variant



Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Received", False
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Functional Mailbox`? Is it an inbox of another account?

Comment: I work at a company and some colleagues share the same Mailbox.
I believe we can call it a shared mailbox, an account whose owner it's not me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the OlDefaultFolders enum for the GetDefaultFolder method?

```
  olFolderDeletedItems = 0x3;
  olFolderOutbox = 0x4;
  olFolderSentMail = 0x5;
  olFolderInbox = 0x6;
  olFolderCalendar = 0x9;
  olFolderContacts = 0xA;
  olFolderJournal = 0xB;
  olFolderNotes = 0xC;
  olFolderTasks = 0xD;
  olFolderDrafts = 0x10;
  olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders = 0x12;
  olFolderConflicts = 0x13;
  olFolderSyncIssues = 0x14;
  olFolderLocalFailures = 0x15;
  olFolderServerFailures = 0x16;
  olFolderJunk = 0x17;
  olFolderRssFeeds = 0x19;
  olFolderToDo = 0x1C;
  olFolderManagedEmail = 0x1D;
  olFolderSuggestedContacts = 0x1E;
```

Comment: I don't think so..
Take a look at my code up above.
The part I am talking about is the  olFolderInbox
I used olFolderInbox just as a test for the rest of my code.
Instead of using olFolderInbox, I need to access a folder called Requirements. 
I don't know how can I do that since I don't own this folder.

Comment: Where exactly does that folder live?

Comment: I mean relative to the top folder or one of the common folders, such as the Inbox?